# ASP.Net MVC passing data from script to new view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Hi everyone and thanks for reading this message at first.

I am currently struggling with an ASP.Net MVC Framework project for passing data between views.

I have a controller Model with Index View and a javascript that helps me getting ids of objects clicked on a 3d model rendered in a canvas. Here is the view :

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <canvas id="viewer"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <btn id="AddEventObjects" class="btn btn-eiffage-red">Create a task</btn>
    <table id="selectedElements" class="table table-striped">
        <thead><tr><th>Selected parts</th></tr></thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewer = new xViewer('viewer');
    var selectedIds = [];
    viewer.on('loaded',
        () => {
            viewer.start();
        });

    viewer.on('pick', function (args) {
        if (args == null || args.id == null) {
            return;
        }        
        var id = args.id;

        //If the id was previously clicked then remove it from the list and remove the highlight
        if (selectedIds.includes(id)) {
            var index = selectedIds.indexOf(id);
            selectedIds.splice(index, 1);            
        } else {            
            selectedIds.push(id);            
        }


        //Add elements to the table
        var table = document.getElementById('selectedElements');
        var oldtbody = document.getElementById('selectedElementsBody');
        if (oldtbody) {
            oldtbody.remove();
        }
        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        tbody.id = "selectedElementsBody";
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedIds.length; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.textContent = selectedProperties[i];
            row.appendChild(cell);
            tbody.appendChild(row);
            table.appendChild(tbody);
        }
    });
    viewer.load('../Content/3d/Maintenance.wexbim');
</script>
```

With the script under I would like to open another window passing the selectedIds array :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#AddEventObjects').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@(Url.Action("AddEventObjects", "Planning"))",
                type: "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                data: { selectedObjects: selectedIds},
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location = "/Planning/AddEventObjects";
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Knowing that my controller Planning has an action called AddEventObjects:

```
public ActionResult AddEventObjects(string[] selectedObjects) {
            ViewBag.Title = "Ajout intervention";
            var addEventObjectsViewModel = new AddEventObjectsViewModel {
                Title = "",
                StartTime = "",
                EndTime = "",
                AllUsers = _context.Users.ToList(),
                SelectedUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>(),
                PostedUsers = new PostedUsers(),
                ObjectsIds = selectedObjects.ToList(),
            };
            addEventObjectsViewModel.PostedUsers.SelectedIds = addEventObjectsViewModel.SelectedUsers.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
            return View(addEventObjectsViewModel);
}
```

I would like it to open the following view that displays the selectedIds :

```
@model Maintenance.Web.Models.AddEventObjectsViewModel

using (Html.BeginForm("AddEvent", "Planning", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h4>Créer une nouvelle intervention</h4>

        <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-row col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ObjectsIds, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; margin-top:20px">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            @if (Model != null) {
                                foreach (var objectId in Model.ObjectsIds) {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@objectId</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-eiffage-red" value="Ajouter" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
```

With a more basic question : how can I pass an array from a javascript in a view to another view?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing an array of data, there are a few ways.  The easiest of ways is to do the following.  Join the array IDS into a comma separated string:

```
var idList = data.PostedUsers.SelectedIds.join(); //comma sep list
window.location = "/Planning/AddEventObjects?ids=" + idList;
```

This would work with what you have very simply; it will build a URL like:

```
/Planning/AddEventObjects?ids=1,2,3,4
```

In the backend, you have a "string ids" parameter, and split it by comma, and use the IDs however you need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went with this solution in the end. Passing data through the url is the only way I found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brian Mains!

I went with passing data in the url as you suggested.
I just used Json serialized data instead of coma separated values :

```
<a id="CreateEvent" class="btn" href="">Créer une intervention</a>
```

...

```
var createLink = "/Planning/AddEventObjects?ids=" + JSON.stringify(model.ids);
$('#CreateEvent').attr("href", createLink);
```

And then in my controller :

```
    public ActionResult AddEventObjects(string ids) {
        if (ids == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        string[] objectIds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(ids);
    }
```